# AWS API Gateway + Lambda: No Auth Header -> Error Message; Auth Header -> No Response

Tags: amazon-web-services, postman, aws-api-gateway, amazon-iam

I'm trying to set up a very basic API, before taking the additional step of integrating Cognito.  Testing the API endpoint within the AWS console works fine. However, I'm not able to get things working in Postman.

In API Gateway, I've connected an endpoint with no parameters to a Lambda function.  The Lambda function returns a hard-coded, static JavaScript object. Clicking the test button here works as expected.
[image]

In the Method Execution screen, I've selected AWS_IAM for authorization and don't require an API key.
[image]

In IAM I created a user named `postman` and attached the `AmazonAPIGatewayInvokeFullAccess` policy (covering all ExecuteAPI resources, for now).
[image]

The API seems to be published correctly, since it complains when I try to access it without an Authorization header.
[image]

But when I use the `AWS Signature` Authoriztion type and enter `postman`'s AccessKey and SecretKey, I get no response at all.
[image]

I'm trying to find access logs to debug, but I'm new to this part of AWS and haven't found anything yet... **What am I missing?**  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try without the region and service name defined in postman? Since they are already part of the URL? Also double check everything. I accidentally had a newline in a Session Token when testing a request from an instance role creds and it causes a no response also... when it worked perfectly fine without the accidental newline.

Comment: I have tried it without the optional fields; same result. I also checked the timeout (set to infinity) and proxy (none).  I know I would need to specify a session token in some use cases, but I don't need anything there now, right?

Comment: Not for permanent creds you don't, so right now you are fine without.

Comment: What are your logs saying? Does API Gateway show an error? Is your lambda being invoked at all? If so what do those logs show?

Comment: The API Gateway Dashboard shows 0 traffic (no API calls or errors).  The monitoring tab of the Lambda function (and its CloudWatch logs) show activity, but they seem to correspond to the test calls through API Gateway, not requests from Postman.  Where else should I look?

Comment: One thing potentially worth noting is that `Missing Authentication Token` is used, by default, as a generic error message in API Gateway -- many different failure conditions will return this same error, presumably in order to avoid giving a would-be attacker any hints as to what is really happening... so it isn't always a safe assumption that this message means anything more definitive than "something isn't working."

Comment: @carpiediem - The only way I have been able to replicate your error is by intentionally using an incorrect URL. I assume you have checked for typos?

Comment: @KMo, thank you for digging into this.  I'm happy to say that you helped me find the solution and I'm a bit embarrassed it that I didn't spot it earlier. I thought I had checked all the fields several times for extra whitespace, but apparently I didn't, since I just found a linebreak in the AccessKey field.  After I took that out, Postman works fine.  If you're interested in the reputation points, feel free to answer this post with a "check for typos" and I'll mark it.  Thanks for your help.